# How to schedule a Selenium application to run periodically?

Tags: selenium, scheduling

I am working on a Selenium application. As per our requirement it must run every 5 minutes. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing builtin to Selenium for running a test every five minutes.  However, there are many Java scheduling packages available, e.g. Quartz.  If you can tell us what research you have done already, we may be able to provide more specific advice.

Comment: Hi Im having the same concern, Im having a selenium webdriver script with TestNg. And I want it to run at some specific time automatically, so i tried to cerate an bat file and then put it on scheduler, so that it can run automatically, as follows : https://stackoverflow.com/a/21751039/5886712 . But Im not getting any output after running the bat file, what could be the issue .

Answer (score 3):

One option in latest Selenium IDE can help you with it as long as you dont need to report any errors or take action when there is an error:

Selenium IDE > Options > Schedule tests to run periodically

[image]

[image]

you can add test cases or test suit to it

Answer (score 1):

Preferably you schedule it with a [build-server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation#Build_automation_servers) like [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/).

The added value of scheduling with a build-server is that it has reporting/alerting features by e-mail or other means to warn you a test is failing.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestions and approach based on the current info provided by you would be:

Please flesh out the question. If you are interested in a more specific/zeroed in  solution,  give us  the environment, selenium version and other aspects you  think would help us help you.

Else help yourself on this [link](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2370/running-selenium-tests-as-a-scheduled-task), which has some useful piece of info.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which platform you are running on, but if you are running on Linux or Mac OS X, then you could use `cron`.

The combination of Selenium and crontab has been asked about, and answered, on SE Stack Overflow a number of times already. Check out:

1. [Execute Python (selenium )script in crontab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20575751/execute-python-selenium-script-in-crontab);
2. [Run selenium with crontab (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23908319/run-selenium-with-crontab-python), and;
3. [Cron job to run Selenium 2 test Suite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225698/cron-job-to-run-selenium-2-test-suite).